# Downloading a file from PHP function in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to download a file from a PHP service in my iOS app.  I use the same PHP service from Android and from the browser and the server part works fine.  I can test the url in the browser and prompts to download the file like you'd expect.
Also I can download the files just fine if I point the url directly at the file from my iOS code.  These are zip files.  I have to use this method because I need to get the file by id and I have to pass a access token string.  These validate OK so they aren't the problem.

When I connect I get a didReceiveResponse with a httpResponse status code of 200 which I'm to believe is OK.  I then get a connectionDidFinishLoading delegate call but never get any data or errors in between.

Here is my connect code:

```
- (BOOL)downloadFile:(NSString *)fileName:(int)fileId
{
    BOOL retVal = FALSE;

    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?id=%d&token=%@", FILE_URL,   fileId, accessToken];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData                                   timeoutInterval:60];


//  Starts the download
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

return TRUE;
}
```

//  Here is the Response code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    int code = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if(code <= 200)
    {
        [responseData setLength:0];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error Code: %d.  Download has Failed.", code];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Error!"
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

//  This is the lonely receive data method.  Never gets called

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

// Failure delegate method, doesn't get called either

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Error!"
                                                message:msg
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Like I said it works from Android and the browser and If I just point the url at the file it will download fine.

I'm stuck and I appreciate any assistance I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I think write two more lines in ur first method download file:

```
- (BOOL)downloadFile:(NSString *)fileName:(int)fileId
{
    BOOL retVal = FALSE;

    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?id=%d&token=%@", FILE_URL,   fileId, accessToken];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData                                   timeoutInterval:60];


//  Starts the download
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


 if (connection) 
    {
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }

return TRUE;
}
```

and make the property of responseData object as nonatomic and retain in ur .h file and synthesize it in ur .m file. Also release it in ur dealloc and make it nil in viewDidUnload.

Also 
I dont know what type of web service u r calling with ur method. But there are two types of webservices GET and POST. and u cannot call POST services only changing GET into POST in ur method [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

Pls try to use AFNetworking classes or ASIHTTPRequest classes
There are some sample projects for webservices that helps u

for AFNetworking :

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/afnetworking-1-0/

http://afnetworking.com/

for ASIHTTPRequest

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request

Comment: Well in this case the responseData never gets used because the code never gets that far.  The process stops with a didReceiveResponse with a [response expectedContentLength] of 0.0.  So it's telling be to expect 0 bytes than no more callbacks.  No Joy.

Comment: Can u tell me which type of service (GET or POST) u r using

Comment: I've tried it with [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; and POST.  Get fails the same way and POST fails with a 406 error.

Comment: GET service can be accessed by using NSURLRequest
and in POST service you need to design HEADER for the data u r sending. Pls check it again

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  But what I tried was the following:    
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData                                   timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

Comment: This is from the server PHP code.  Definitely a GET.
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET")
        $this->response('',406);

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was the url on the server.  There was a security setting that had been set on the Apple files folder and not the Android files folder.

Comment: This was a while ago but going for the long shot... do you remember any of the settings on those folders?